# Forming a JSON String using GSon

Tags: java, android, gson

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JSON {

    public String name;

    public HashMap<String, String> Credentials = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public JSON(String name){
        Credentials.put(name, name);
    }

}

JSON json = new JSON("Key1");
new Gson().toJson(json);
```

I get the following value as output.

> {"Credentials":{"Key1":"Key1"}}

Now how would i create an JSONObject something like this below using Gson.

Comment: Do you want to use maps or do you want regular POJOs? Is this more or less representative of a single Credentials object and single Header object, which have their own attributes? In the case of Credentials is it just two additional POJOs PrimeSuiteCredential & VendorCredential?

Comment: @DaveG: i am not sure of the right approach here. yes in our case its just adding two more objects... PrimeSuiteCredential and VendorCreedential.

Comment: take a look at the solution provided by Brian below - basically you should build your model object (POJO) to represent the structure as concisely as possible.  Add set/get methods in standard Bean style and then use GSON to convert it.  You shouldn't have to do too much work to provide the export and I'll post an answer in a moment to show what I mean.

Comment: @DaveG: Thanks.... a lot... i am new to this in creating a JSON object using java.... it would be great if i can see one complete way which i can understand and use the same across for many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what @Brian is doing, you just need the auto serialization piece.

What you do is the following, and I have to state, this is with regard to a single object at the moment.  You'll have to look through the GSON documentation for more detail on this if you're dealing with a collection of objects at the top level.

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
Writer output= ... /// wherever you're putting information out to
JsonWriter jsonWriter= new JsonWriter(output);
// jsonWriter.setIndent("\t"); // uncomment this if you want pretty output
// jsonWriter.setSerializeNulls(false); // uncomment this if you want null properties to be emitted
gson.toJson(myObjectInstance, MyObject.class, jsonWriter);
jsonWriter.flush();
jsonWriter.close();
```

Hopefully that will give you enough context to work with. Gson should be smart enough to figure out your properties and give them sensible names in the output.

Comment: Just looking at documentation: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); can also be used to prettify output

Comment: I am right now too confused... on creating the entire json string in that format... can u help me out in a chat.

Comment: HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> Credentials = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>(); How would add values to this HashMap.

Comment: @theJava - room opened for chat under same title as this question

Answer (score 2):

You create a POJO that matches your JSON data structure:

```
public class MyObject {

    public HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> Credentials;
    public HashMap<String, String> Header;

}
```

**Edit for comments below:**

This is kinda "data structures 101" but ... you have a JSON Object that boils down to a Hash table that contains two hash tables, the first of which contains two more hash tables.

You can represent this simply as I show above, or you could create all the POJOs and use those:

```
public class Credentials {
    private PrimeSuiteCredential primeSuiteCredential;
    private VendorCredential vendorCredential;

   // getters and setters

}

public class PrimeSuiteCedential {
    private String primeSuiteSiteId;
    private String primeSuiteUserName;
    ...

    // Getters and setters
}

public class VendorCredential {
    private String vendorLogin;
    ...

    // getters and setters
}


public class Header {
    private String destinationSiteId;
    ...

    // getters and setters

}

public class MyObject {
    public Credentials credentials;
    public Header header;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Brian Roach: Can u give me a complete example. I need to implement this across 100 places forming new JSONObject....

Comment: I liked your first approach, how would i form that structure... should i add the objects via the constructor... thanks a lot for your time. the second approach seems to be creating too many class files.